# Getting text from multiple divs with spans inside - XPath

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract ingredients from this site (**using python, scrapy and xpath only**): 
http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/gin-orange-juice-braised-endives

I use the following xpath:

```
//*[@itemprop="recipeIngredient"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()
```

I need the ingredients as a list like this:

```
 ["3 tablespoons extra-virgin olive oil",
 "10 medium Belgian endives, halved lengthwise",
 "1/2 cup gin",
 "Salt and freshly ground black pepper"
 ...]
```

But it gives me a lot of spaces inside:

```
[u'\n  ', u'3 tablespoons', u'\n  ', u' \n                extra-virgin olive oil\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u'10 ', u'\n  ', u' \n                medium Belgian endives, halved lengthwise\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u'1/2 cup', u'\n  ', u' \n                gin\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n  ', u' \n                Salt and freshly ground black pepper\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u'1 cup', u'\n  ', u' \n                fresh orange juice\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u'4 tablespoons', u'\n  ', u' \n                unsalted butter\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u'2 tablespoons', u'\n  ', u' \n                honey\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u'2 ', u'\n  ', u' \n                scallions, white and pale green parts only, thinly sliced\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u'2 tablespoons', u'\n  ', u' \n                salted roasted pumpkin seeds\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n  ', u' \n                Balsamic vinegar, for drizzling\n             ', u'\n  ', u' ', u'\n']
```

After stripping each item with python (2.7):

```
 ["3 tablespoons",
 "extra-virgin olive oil",
 "10",
 "medium Belgian endives, halved lengthwise",
 "1/2 cup",
 "gin",
 "Salt and freshly ground black pepper",
 ...]
```

Each of the ingredients is inside a div, like this:

```html
<div itemprop="recipeIngredient"  >
  <span>3 tablespoons</span>
  <span> 
                extra-virgin olive oil
             </span>
  <span> </span>
</div>
```

If I use normalize-text, like this:

```
normalize-space(//*[@itemprop="recipeIngredient"])
```

I get only this:

```
3 tablespoons extra-virgin olive oil
```

which is amazing, but I need all the divs and not only the first one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use python in the end, with a bit of looping and more xpath on the original xpath:

```
if response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="recipeIngredient"]'):
    ingredients = []
    for item in response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="recipeIngredient"]'):
        item = item.xpath("span/text()").extract()
        item = " ".join([" ".join(elem.split()) for elem in item])
        ingredients.append(item)

    raw_recipe["ingredients"] = ingredients
```

Result (with an extra space, but I don't mind):

```
["3 tablespoons extra-virgin olive oil ", "10 medium Belgian endives, halved lengthwise ", "1/2 cup gin ", " Salt and freshly ground black pepper ", "1 cup fresh orange juice ", "4 tablespoons unsalted butter ", "2 tablespoons honey ", "2 scallions, white and pale green parts only, thinly sliced ", "2 tablespoons salted roasted pumpkin seeds ", " Balsamic vinegar, for drizzling "]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below `XPath` expression:

```
//div[@itemprop="recipeIngredient"]/string(normalize-space())
```

Comment: It doesn't compile as xpath, also, modification gives me:

    <span>3 tablespoons</span>
<span>
                extra-virgin olive oil
             </span>
<span>10 </span>
<span>
                medium Belgian endives, halved lengthwise
             </span>
<span>1/2 cup</span>
<span>
                gin
             </span>
<span>
                Salt and freshly ground black pepper
             </span>

Comment: I'm quite sure that this is a valid `XPath` expression and it returns required values... You can check it with http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. What is the `Python` library that you use?

Comment: This is the layout that compiles:

    //div[@itemprop="recipeIngredient"][string(normalize-space())]

Comment: Yes, but it has totally different meaning... Do you get any exceptions with my `XPath`?

Comment: I'm using FireFox Xpath extension and it says "Syntax Error"

Comment: You mean like `FirePath`? Try `string(normalize-space(//div[@itemprop="recipeIngredient"]/.))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136467/discussion-between-elvira-gandelman-and-andersson).

Answer (score -1):

Use the below jQuery script:

```
var $=jQuery;
var list=[];
$('.field-ingredients').each(function () {
  var ingredient=[]
  $(this).find('span').each(function () {
    ingredient.push($(this).text().trim());    
  });
  list.push(ingredient.join(" ").trim());
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: I can only use python, this is not code that is running on my website, sorry.

Comment: She requested a solution in python, this is not a relevant answer